# Excel formula advice

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to use Excel to calculate delivery costs based on postcode data and volume. I have base data with all the postcodes and the costs based on the volume delivered. I want my main table to be able to put in the postode and volume and the table to automatically bring up the delivery cost i.e
If post code is AL and the volume is 1 the delivery cost automatically populates.

I know its a complicated formula. I have grouped the postcodes into Group A,B,C,D,E,F,G to simplify slightly. I have added pictures to help explain what I am after

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to use INDEX and MATCH. Without providing an editable example it's difficult to give you a working formula.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your table is on another sheet, which I have named `BaseData`, then this should work.  Change the ranges to match your data, `$C$2:$S$34` being the numeric data and `$A$2:$A$34` being the Postcodes.  Copy the formula into the first Cost cell, which I assume is cell `C2`, then drag it down.  This assumes that cell `A2` is the first Post code and that cell `B2` is the Volume for that code.

`=INDEX(BaseData!$C$2:$S$34,MATCH(A2,BaseData!$A$2:$A$34),B2)`

`INDEX(range,row,column)` Range is the field of data `BaseData!$C$2:$S$34`, Row is found by finding the match for the Postcode `A2` which returns the row number within that range `BaseData!$A$2:$A$34`. Since your table seems to have sequential volumes in the header, I just used the Volume value `B2` instead of another `MATCH` term for the Column value.

I'm not sure what the %5, 7.50%, etc. columns are used for so I didn't address them.

Comment: Can you please give a rundown of how the formula works?  For example, what is the `B2` for at the end?

Comment: @ChrisRogers, I edited and clarified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it very easily using VLOOKUP and MATCH functions.
I have done it successfully. I am attaching image of test spreadsheet, where you can find, Data, Formula and Result.
[Click to see](http://geekpic.net/pm-DHR17Q.html)

Comment: Good approach! Please upload the picture taken by screen capture so it'll be better quality.

Comment: @Mate: Ok, Mate. Will try that from next time. Thanks for appreciation.